# Prove uniform convergence for $g_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n x^k$ on interval $[-a,a]$, $a \in (0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n x^k$. I am trying to prove that the sequence of functions $(g_0, g_1, \ldots)$ converges uniformly to $g(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ for $x \in [-a,a]$ with $a \in (0,1)$.

Toward this end, I've proven that $g_n$ converges to $g$ pointwise and am on the next step of showing that convergence is also uniform. Here I have that \begin{align}
|g(x) - g_n(x)| = \left|\frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{1 - x^{n+1}}{1-x}\right| = \frac{|x^{n+1}|}{|1-x|} \le \frac{a^{n+1}}{1-a}.
\end{align}

Now I just need to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $n > 0$ such that $\frac{a^{n+1}}{1-a} < \epsilon$.

This seems stupidly easy, but I'm having trouble proving this simple statement. Specifically, \begin{align}
\frac{a^{n+1}}{1-a} < \epsilon &\iff (n+1)\log(a) < \log(\epsilon(1-a)) \\
&\iff n < \frac{\log(\epsilon(1-a))}{\log(a)} - 1.
\end{align}

However, here the inequality is going the wrong way. I need a constant "$C$" such that the statement holds for $n > C$.

What am I missing?

Comment: $log(a) < 0$ for $a\in(0,1)$, so the direction of the inequality is flipped when dividing by it. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a\in(0,1)$, $\log(a)$ is negative.  So, when you divide by it, the inequality changes direction, and you get $n > \frac{\log(\epsilon(1-a))}{\log(a)} - 1$ just like you want.

Comment: Duh. Thanks :-)